# Why does g++ make my code execute in a different order than written and how do I disable this "optimization"?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string* stuff(NULL);

    printf("allocating memory..."); //line 2

    stuff = new std::string[500000000]; //line 3

    delete [] stuff; //line 4

    return 0;
}
```

when executed runs line 3 (and possibly line 4) before line 2. Now I know this is probably some good optimization feature but sometimes the right order is needed.

Comment: What makes you think that line 2 is run after line 3? (It most likely is not.)

Comment: @Michael Krelin - hacker: I just thought of that too, which is why I deleted my last comment. :-)

Comment: @Insilico, and I deleted mine because you deleted yours and because I've just seen the answer hinting at this :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
printf("allocating memory..."); //line 2
```

In many architectures you have buffered output, which means that what you print on the screen is not shown immediately but stored in a memory buffer. To flush the buffer and ensure that he is printed immediately, you can use

```
printf("allocating memory...\n"); //line 2 with the \n character that flushes the buffer
```

although I didn't find anything to prove this besides personal experience, or alternatively, if you don't want to go to a new line (and be absolutely sure of flushing) you can use `fflush(stdout)` right after line 2.

Comment: I don't think `\n` guarantees flushing (unlike c++ std::endl).

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I had thought of that too, that's why I'm searching for some references.

Comment: The behaviour is inherited from C (7.19.3 of C99). Streams may be _unbuffered_, _line buffered_ or _fully buffered_. Standard error is not fully buffered and standard out is only allowed to be fully buffered if it is determined not to be connected to an interactive device. This allows stdout to be _line buffered_ or _unbuffered_ and it is usually _line buffered_ on most 'unices' meaning that a newline character will flush it.

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesBailey, I knew it's a common experience, but I thought there's no guarantee. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't know printf had the buffering but now I know what flush() does. thanks

Comment: This does nothing to guarantee the ordering of the other statements. The compiler has zero requirement to maintain ordering beyond visible affects, volatiles, and synchronization. In the provided code it can even remove the allocation entirely if it wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

*-O0* flag disables all optimizations in GCC.

But the effect you are observing is most probably not due to an optimization but rather a result of file IO buffering.

Inserting *fflush(stdout)* just after *printf(...)* will make IO system flush the buffer which in case of logging to a file should give you the right order of events (assuming you are logging *malloc()* calls to the same file and this is where you observe out of order events).

Answer (score 3):

In C++, you might want to write it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string* stuff(NULL);

    std::cout << "allocating memory..."; //line 2
    std::cout.flush();   // ensures the buffer is actually written to the terminal right here

    stuff = new std::string[500000000]; //line 3

    delete [] stuff; //line 4

    return 0;
}
```